# Determine the projection of each vector on a plane in ON system

Tags: vector-spaces

(ON system) Determine the projection of the vectors $u=(-2,2,4)$ and $w=(1,1,3)$ on the plan pi with the equation

$2x+y-z = 0,$

which means to determine the vectors $v$ and $z$ that are parallell with the plane pi and such that $u-v$ respectively $w-z$ and are perpendicular to the plane pi.

I know it might be a bit difficult to understand the question, but I have translated from another language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

$U\text{=}(-2,2,4)$,

$V\text{=}(1,1,3)$

and normalvector

$N\text{=}(2,1,-1)$

calculate

$X=U-\frac{ <U,N>}{<N,N>}N$

and similar

$Y=V-\frac{ <V,N>}{<N,N>}N$.

Bracketsymbol means scalarproduct of two vectors.

Then $<X,N>=0$, therefore $X$ is point of the plane.
Same is true in case $<Y,N>=0$.

Sorry for changing names of variables.

By the way: For me

$X\text{=}(0,3,3)$

$Y\text{=}(1,1,3)$.

Comment: According to the answer sheet you got the correct answer. You used the general formula for the projection of $X$ orthogonal to $U$ and the same thing with the other case? But how did the information below at the end of the text helped? You know, those with additional conditions described?

Comment: Purpose is just to control my result.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks for the quick answer!